# Recover from partition error (easeus freeware tool)

Tags: partitioning, easeus-partition-manager, partitionmanager

I used easeus partition tool from windows (the gparted usb sticks I was making wouldn' boot). On my hard disk I had a nameless partition (*), an operating partition (c:), a recovery partition and several gigabytes of unallocated space.

I moved the recovery partition towards the end of the disk leaving a few gigabytes at the very end, then I enlarged the operating partition from the end of the nameless one to the beginning of the recovery one.

At reboot the screen listed three operations: the first one was to enlarge the nameless partition by a few megabytes (which I hadn't told it to), the second was enlarging the operating partition (without moving the recovery partition first), after this it immidiately output this error: "**Message (-1):Unknown error. There may be some error on operating partition. Press any key to reboot!**".

The system is now booting to the Windows logo and then stalling on a black screen. How can I recover my system?

This is what I get by booting in gParted.
[image: gParted]

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: I edited with explicit question